# Message "converted to a comment by owner" is incorrect when user self-deletes post after moderator converts to comment and undeletes

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools, deleted-answers

Obviously a trivial corner-case, but:

[image: converted to a comment by owner]

Looking at the revision history, we see:

[image: revision history codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/40181/revisions]

A moderator converted the post to a comment, and then undeleted the answer stub. The original poster of the answer then self-deleted it, causing this incorrect message to show up.

I'm assuming this is because the logic for determining what to show as the deletion reason goes something like this:

```
if (revisionHistoryThingies.contains(MOD_CONVERTS_TO_COMMENT)) {
    output "converted to a comment by blah blah"
}
```

Could this be fixed so that it makes sure that the *most recent* deletion event was a "convert to comment," and not just check whether it happened at some point in time?

Comment: Just thinking aloud, this would also be the case in case of spam answer that would be undeleted by a mod then deleted again in the ordinary way.

Comment: This report extends beyond owner self-deletions, and a developer has given an official response at [Difficult to lose the "converted to a comment" status message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327050/difficult-to-lose-the-converted-to-a-comment-status-message)