# Difficult to lose the "converted to a comment" status message

Tags: bug, status-deferred, answers, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

If an answer is converted to a comment and then subsequently undeleted, and then deleted again (without being converted to a comment), the message beneath the post still reads:

[image: Converted to comment]

If the answer is then undeleted again, and the comment is deleted, and then the answer is deleted again, the message still reads:

[image: Converted to comment]

This happens if the mod who converted the comment is not the same, or is the same, as the mod performing the subsequent undeleting and deleting. The initial undeleting was performed at least six months after the initial conversion to comment (if that is of any relevance).

---

Why or how did I discover this? Because there was a ridiculous answer that had unfortunately been converted to a comment, and I wanted the answer both deleted and *not* to have the *converted to a comment by XXX* status message, and instead just have the *deleted by XXX* status message.

Comment: Possible duplicate/Related: [Message "converted to a comment by owner" is incorrect when user self-deletes post after moderator converts to comment and undeletes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242444/message-converted-to-a-comment-by-owner-is-incorrect-when-user-self-deletes-po)

Comment: @Catija does the status-deferred here means "This is not on our radar and will not be done in the near future", or "This has been added to our internal backlog and will be done as part of routine bug fixing"? I've seen both being widely used recently, and it's getting very confusing.

Comment: The latter, @ShadowWizardChasingStars